# jaxb @XmlIDREF @XmlID work amazingly

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations

jaxb @XmlIDREF @XmlID work amazingly

**my xml input is**

```
<dept>
    <courses>
        <course id="1" units="4" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Fundamentals of Programming"/>
        <course id="2" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Advanced Programming">
            <pre>1</pre>
        </course>
        <course id="3" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Discrete Mathematics">
            <pre>1</pre>
        </course>
        <course id="4" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Data Structures"/>
        <course id="5" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Database Systems">
            <pre>4</pre>
            <pre>2</pre>
        </course>
        <course id="6" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Internet Engineering">
            <pre>4</pre>
            <pre>2</pre>
            <co>5</co>
        </course>
        <course id="7" units="3" level="GRAD" name="Formal Methods"/>
        <course id="8" units="3" level="GRAD" name="Advanced Networks"/>
        <course id="9" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Fundamentals of Management"/>
        <course id="10" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Fundamentals of IT"/>
        <course id="11" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Multimedia"/>
        <course id="12" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Network Security"/>
        <course id="13" units="3" level="UNDERGRAD" name="Elearning"/>
    </courses>
    <profs>
        <prof firstName="Ramtin" id="1"/>
        <prof firstName="Ahmad" id="2"/>
        <prof firstName="Hesham" id="3"/>
        <prof firstName="Fatemeh" id="4"/>
        <prof firstName="Mahmood" id="5"/>
        <prof firstName="Mahmoudreza" id="6"/>
        <prof firstName="Fattaneh" id="7"/>
        <prof firstName="Azadeh" id="8"/>
        <prof firstName="Siamak" id="9"/>
    </profs>
    <terms>
        <term id="1">
            <offering id="1" prof="6" course="1" section="1" time="1" capacity="10"/>
            <offering id="2" prof="1" course="2" section="1" time="1" capacity="10"/>
            <offering id="3" prof="9" course="3" section="1" time="2" capacity="10"/>
            <offering id="4" prof="3" course="4" section="1" time="3" capacity="10"/>
            <offering id="5" prof="1" course="7" section="1" time="6" capacity="10"/>
        </term>
        <term>
            <offering id="6" prof="1" course="2" section="1" time="5" capacity="10"/>
            <offering id="7" prof="9" course="3" section="1" time="6" capacity="10"/>
            <offering id="8" prof="4" course="8" section="1" time="6" capacity="10"/>
            <offering id="9" prof="2" course="1" section="1" time="1" capacity="10"/>
        </term>
    </terms>
    <students>
        <student firstName="Gholam" lastName="Patoobaf" program="1" id="810190420">
            <studyrec grade="9.0" offering="1" status="FAILED"/>
            <studyrec grade="0.0" offering="9" status="INPROGRESS"/>
        </student>
        <student firstName="Ghamar" lastName="Aghrabparast" program="1" id="810190421">
            <studyrec grade="16.0" offering="1" status="PASSED"/>
            <studyrec grade="0.0" offering="6" status="INPROGRESS"/>
            <studyrec grade="0.0" offering="7" status="INPROGRESS"/>
        </student>
    </students>
</dept>
```

---

my java class for element: **offering**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Offering {
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    private String id;
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlIDREF
    private Prof prof;
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlIDREF
    private Course course;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String section;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String time;
    @XmlAttribute
    private int capacity;

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setProf(Prof prof) {
        this.prof = prof;
    }

    public Prof getProf() {
        return prof;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object t) {
        if (t instanceof Offering) {
            if(((Offering)t).getId().equals(this.id)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

my java class for element: **Prof**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Prof {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String firstName;   
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstName = firstname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

---

so if i simply load and save the input file to another file
i amazingly see this:
in offering elements which the prof id is less than 6, the prog attribute is not shown and are null in java context
but offerings with prof id of 6 or more have the prof attribute properly

this event also occurs for course attribute of offering but for 9 instead of 6
as you see part of my output below:

```
...
 <offering id="1" prof="6" section="1" time="1" capacity="10"/>
 <offering id="2" section="1" time="1" capacity="10"/>
 <offering id="3" prof="9" section="1" time="2" capacity="10"/>
 <offering id="4" section="1" time="3" capacity="10"/>
 <offering id="5" section="1" time="6" capacity="10"/>
...
```

it has no rule for example jaxb works properly for this input xml not just for id greater than 6:

```
<offering id="1" prof="3" course="1" section="1" time="1" capacity="10"/>
<offering id="2" prof="3" course="2" section="1" time="1" capacity="10"/>
<offering id="3" prof="9" course="3" section="1" time="2" capacity="10"/>
<offering id="4" prof="8" course="4" section="1" time="3" capacity="10"/>
<offering id="5" prof="6" course="7" section="1" time="6" capacity="10"/>
```

Comment: ok, it has no rule for example jaxb works properly for this:

Comment: Here is an example that demonstrates how `@XmlID` and `@XmlIDREF` are designed to work together:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem resolved by implementing an IDResolver